# Tell NetworkManager to ignore or not probe rfcomm0

Tags: console, tty, bluetooth, networkmanager, ubuntu-12.10

I'm trying to remotely connect to a system via Bluetooth but am running into problems.  Here's what I'm trying to do...

On the remote device I'd like to have the following running:  `rfcomm -r watch 0 3 getty -L {} 9600`

What that does is: Watch on the bluetooth device "0" for an rfcomm connection on channel 3.  When one occurs, run `getty -L {} 9600` and replace the "{}" with the device created.  (usually `/dev/rfcomm0` in this case)

I then should be able to connect to the remote device by running on my laptop:  `rfcomm connect 0 11:22:33:44:55:66 3`  (tells it to use device "0" to connect to the bluetooth address "11:22:33:44:55:66" on channel 3)   I then should get a serial console on the remote device by typing `screen /dev/rfcomm0`.

### The problem...

Everything should be working fine except NetworkManager on my laptop somehow "sees" the connection and tries to probe it as if it was a modem.  It sends `AT+GCAP` strings and `~x�~` but the remote end is running getty and is expecting login credentials.

I'm able to get it to work by making the rfcomm0 connection first:

```
remote$  rfcomm -r watch 0 3
laptop$  rfcomm connect 0 11:22:33:44:55:66 3
```

wait about 60 seconds for the NetworkManger to stop probing `/dev/rfcomm0`

```
remote$  getty -L rfcomm0 9600
laptop$  screen /dev/rfcomm0 9600
```

However, in order to do this, I already need to have console access to the remote device in order to run the getty comamnd

### Question

So, is there any way to tell NetworkManager to ignore `/dev/rfcomm` or to tell it to not probe the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very old question, but in case anyone ends up here via Google, a straightforward solution that worked for me was to create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-rfcomm.rules` with the following content:

```
# ignore rfcomm0 device for now
KERNEL=="rfcomm0", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
```

ModemManager will ignore the device in the future. Note: this is a catch-all rule that will match any rfcomm device, so if you actually want to use one as a modem in the future, you would have to disable the rule again.